# Django save() does not work

Tags: mysql, database, django, model

I'm writing an elections application.  In the process, I've defined an Election model and a Candidate model.

Note: I'm using Django version 1.3.7, Python 2.7.1.

One of Election's methods,

```
Election.count_first_place(self)
```

is intended to count the number of first place votes each candidate receives and update the candidates' numVotes attribute. But for some reason they all stay at zero, no matter the ballots.

Note: I'm implementing STV so each ballot contains an array(ballot.voteArray) of Candidates in order of most preferred (position zero) to least preferred (position n).  I've implemented this list with a PickledObjectField (see [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-picklefield)).

```
models.py

class Candidate(models.Model):
    election = models.ForeignKey("Election")
    numVotes = models.FloatField(blank=True)

class Ballot(models.Model):
    election = models.ForeignKey("Election", related_name = "ballot_set")
    voteArray = PickledObjectField(null=True,blank=True)

class Election(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    candidates = models.ManyToManyField(Candidate,related_name="elections_in",null=True,blank=True)

    def count_first_place(self):

    #retrieve all of the ballots cast in this election

    ballots = Ballot.objects.filter(election = self)
    for ballot in ballots.all():

        # the first element of a ballot's voteArray is a Candidate object
        first_place_choice = ballot.voteArray[0]
        first_place_choice.numVotes += 1
        first_place_choice.save()
        ballot.save()
        self.save()
```

Here is what happens when I run a test:

Note: I realize that I am saving way more often than is necessary. Just being absolutely sure while I test this thing that it saves when it needs to.

```
elec = Election(position="Student Body President")
elec.save()
j = Candidate(election=elec,numVotes=0)
j.save()
e = Candidate(election=elec,numVotes=0)
e.save()
b = Candidate(election=elec,numVotes=0)
b.save()
elec.candidates.add(j,e,b)
elec.save()

ballot1 = Ballot(election=elec,voteArray=[j,e,b])
ballot1.save()
ballot2 = Ballot(election=elec,voteArray=[j,b,e])
ballot2.save()
ballot3 = Ballot(election=elec,voteArray[e,b,j])
ballot3.save()
```

So after this bit, j has two 2 place votes, and e has 1. But when I run

```
elec.count_first_place()
```

j still has zero votes, as do e and b.

What's up with that????

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange table structure. Pickling other model instances is a very bad idea: the pickled versions will not update when their database rows do. Really you should be storing an array of candidate IDs, or even better create a many-to-many relationship from Ballot to Candidate with a through table indicating position.

But I think your problem is simpler than that. You say that the objects still have zero votes: that is because you have not updated those particular instances. Again, there is no direct relationship between a Django instance and the database row, other than on loading and saving. You'll need to reload the objects from the database to see any updates.

Comment: I didn't realize you could utilize such a thing as a "through table" to indicate the position of elements in a many-to-many relationship.  Is that the best way to handle data such as an array of votes that is endowed with a particular order that must be recalled? Also, what else is strange about the table structure? Note that it is a bit simplified so as to not clutter the question with unnecessary detail.

Comment: Decided to implement a linked list instead because a through table didn't meet our needs...by which I mean of course that I couldn't make it work.